# Trigger application from web page

Tags: angular, web-applications

I have developed an application in Windows with a GUI. This GUI has multiple buttons. Each of the buttons will perform certain functions.

I am developing a web page where there will be HTML buttons. When user will click the html button, that button should trigger windows application button in backend.

Example:

If i have developed a calculator in windows which has 4 buttons (Add,Sub,Mul,Div). Now we can have web application which contains 4 buttons. When a user clicks the add button on web page, this button should invoke the calculator add function.

Is there any method to achieve this?